# R Can i store a location in something so i can reference it multiple times without having to retype it or if it changes?

Tags: r

I have five files that are all part of the same thing and intermingled in them are occasional exports of csv files.  Currently, i have the full path written out for each of them, but i had to change a folder and then go through all of the files and find every reference and change them too.

Is there a way in R to store text, like "C:\R\Folder\New" so that then i can just reference an object or something and then i only have to change the path once?

In SAS i'd use a %let statement.

Maybe something like??

`path <- "C:\R\Folder\New"`

And then:

```
write.table(grouped_ageck, file="??PATH??\\qc\\ageck.csv", sep=",", row.names=F)
```

Comment: Use paste, or take a look at sprintf()

Comment: I already set the working directory, but i have subfolders in there and subfolders in there, so there's always a deeper path. It was further in that the path changed.